# How to convert cloudant.document to json

Tags: python, cloudant

with cloudant(CLOUDANT_USERNAME, CLOUDANT_PW, account=CLOUDANT_USERNAME) as client:

```
mydb = client[CLOUDANT_DB]
for doc in mydb:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    #print(type(doc))
    data = **some_function(doc)
    df = json_normalize(data, 'record',...)
```

with above sample code i am trying to convert a doc, obtained from iterating a cloudant db, into a json so that i can then normalize it. However the type of doc is cloudant.document.Document and json.load etc. don't work on it. Any suggestion is welcome for **

Answer (score 0):

The `Document` class has a `.json()` method. See https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant/blob/master/src/cloudant/document.py#L123

It will also convert to `dict` using `d = dict(doc)` if you wish.